# Running distributed-process's Process type in IO

Tags: haskell, distributed

I'm trying to run the `channelsDemo` from the [distributed-process](https://haskell-distributed.github.io/) documentation, but when I try to run `channelsDemo` from `main` as follows:

```
main = channelsDemo
```

I get the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type `IO ()` with actual type `Process ()`

Here is the `channelsDemo` function:

```
channelsDemo :: Process ()
channelsDemo = do
    (sp, rp) <- newChan :: Process (SendPort String, ReceivePort String)

    -- send on a channel
    spawnLocal $ sendChan sp "hello!"

    -- receive on a channel
    m <- receiveChan rp
    say $ show m
```

I see the problem, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

`distributed-process` has a [`runProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-0.6.1/docs/Control-Distributed-Process-Node.html#v:runProcess) function which seems to have the right signature:

```
runProcess :: LocalNode -> Process () -> IO ()
```

and there's a way to create a `LocalNode`:

```
newLocalNode :: Transport -> RemoteTable -> IO LocalNode
```